# Laravel Keeps loading till gateway timeout without any exception

Tags: laravel

When there's an error it only logs it but doesn't throw an exception. How can I correct this anomaly? Because it doesn't throw exceptions the page will keep loading and using up the server resources, especially CPU

Using Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1 and Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Consider this scenario: I'm emailing all 10,000 users in my system, and it takes approximately 1 second to send an email per user. We're looking at 10k seconds, or almost 3 hours just to send emails. Now, to send all these emails, I'm clicking a button which redirects me to route so that the page will keep loading and using up resources until all emails are sent (which will take 3 hours).

But there's a catch. Your server has a timeout for a request, to prevent scenarios like this where your server will just load for hours, hogging up memory and CPU.

To resolve this, you can do several things. One option is that you can set up a [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) for these jobs. Second, you can increase the timeout (not recommended).

For example, before your request...

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 5 min limit
// the rest of your code to process...
```

Keep in mind that your server (nginx) can also have a limit which you'd have to change manually.

But it's best to handle these long processing tasks using a queue.

Comment: I appreciate your response...but I was only loading a page that its query gets less than 20 records. It turned out the problem was the livewire config file...it sounds weird but as soon as I deleted it everything started loading normally.